# Canceling request from ancillary thread to force MPI_Wait to return

Tags: c++, mpi

I am trying to cancel an asynchronous operation initiated with `MPI_Irecv`. In a thread, I have a loop that continuously listen to requests with consecutive calls to `MPI_Irecv` and `MPI_Wait`. To exit the loop cleanly, I would like to cancel the request, e.g. call `MPI_Cancel` from another thread.

From what I understand, `MPI_Cancel` marks the communication for cancellation  is and, quoting the specifications:

> If a communication is marked for cancellation, then a `MPI_WAIT` call for that communication is guaranteed to return.

The following code shows that this does not work as I intend, since `MPI_WAIT` never returns -tested with recent MS-MPI on Windows and MPICH2 on Linux.

```cpp
#include <mpi.h>

#include <iostream>
#include <future>


using namespace std::literals::chrono_literals;

void async_cancel(MPI_Request *request)
{
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(1s);

    std::cout << "Before MPI_Cancel" << std::endl;

    int res = MPI_Cancel(request);
    if (res != MPI_SUCCESS)
        std::cerr << "MPI_Cancel failed" << std::endl;

    std::cout << "After MPI_Cancel" << std::endl;
}


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int provided;
    MPI_Init_thread(&argc, &argv, MPI_THREAD_MULTIPLE, &provided);

    if (provided != MPI_THREAD_MULTIPLE)
        std::cout << "MPI_Init_thread could not provide MPI_THREAD_MULTIPLE" << std::endl;

    int rank, numprocs;
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &numprocs);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);


    MPI_Request request;
    MPI_Status status;

    int buffer;

    if (rank == 0)
    {
        MPI_Irecv(&buffer, 1, MPI_INT, 1, 123, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &request);

        auto res = std::async(std::launch::async, &async_cancel, &request);

        std::cout << "Before MPI_Wait" << std::endl;

        MPI_Wait(&request, &status);

        std::cout << "After MPI_Wait " << std::endl;
    }
    else
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(2s);

    MPI_Finalize();

    return 0;
}
```

Is this an implementation issue? Is there a better way to force `MPI_Wait` to return?

---

**EDIT**: The code (updated with @Zulan and @amlucas comments) actually works for most implementations but MS-MPI.

Comment: I have just submitted an issue with [Github MS-MPI](https://github.com/microsoft/Microsoft-MPI/issues/18)

Answer (score 0):

`MPI_Init` initialized MPI for single threaded calls.
Try using `MPI_Init_thread` instead, which allows you to use thread safe MPI calls.

Comment: I have updated the snippet to use `MPI_Init_thread` (as my real code do) but the issue remains.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to ensure properly threaded MPI, e.g. by replacing `MPI_Init` with

```
int thread_level;
MPI_Init_thread(&argc, &argv, MPI_THREAD_MULTIPLE, &thread_level);
if (thread_level != MPI_THREAD_MULTIPLE)
{
    std::cout << "Invalid thread level " << thread_level << "\n";
    return -1;
}
```

This is necessary whenever you want to concurrently call any MPI functions.
For me this works with OpenMPI 4.0.1 or Intel MPI 2019.0.0.
However, you further need remove the `MPI_Request_free` as it is redundant with the `MPI_Wait` which does also clean up the request.

Now while this appears to work and MPI imposes no restrictions on concurrently calling MPI functions with the same request. However, I would not quite say that the wording of the standard explicitly allows for your particular use-case - and even if so,  that seems like an easy thing to get wrong in an implementation.

If you are having trouble, you could consider using a `MPI_Test` loop - at the expense of latency and energy consumption. Another alternative would be a dummy receive request and `MPI_Waitany`. Instead of `MPI_Cancel`, you then send a message that matches the dummy request.

Comment: I have updated the snippet to remove the unnecessary call to `MPI_Request_free` and can also report that this works with MPICH 3.2.1 on Linux while it fails with MS-MPI 10.
Thanks for the alternative solutions, I'll give it a try!